# How to parse all the text content from the HTML using Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I wanted to extract an email message content. It is in html content, used the **BeautifulSoup** to fetch the From, To and subject. On fetching the body content, it fetches the first line alone. It leaves the remaining lines and paragraph.

I miss something over here, how to read all the lines/paragraphs.

**CODE:**

```
email_message = mail.getEmail(unreadId)
print (email_message['From'])
print (email_message['Subject'])

if email_message.is_multipart():
    for payload in email_message.get_payload():
        bodytext = email_message.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
        if type(bodytext) is list:
            bodytext = ','.join(str(v) for v in bodytext)
else:
    bodytext = email_message.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
    if type(bodytext) is list:
        bodytext = ','.join(str(v) for v in bodytext)
print (bodytext)
parsedContent = BeautifulSoup(bodytext)
body = parsedContent.findAll('p').getText()
print body
```

**Console:**

```
body = parsedContent.findAll('p').getText()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

When I use

```
body = parsedContent.find('p').getText()
```

It fetches the first line of the content and it is not printing the remaining lines.

**Added**

After getting all the lines from the html tag, I get = symbol at the end of each line and also **&nbsp ;** , **&lt** is displayed.How to overcome those.

**Extracted text:**

> Dear first,All of us at GenWatt are glad to have xyz as a
>   customer. I would like to introduce myself as your Account
>   Manager.  Should you = have any questions, please feel free to
>   call me at  or email me at ash= wis@xyz.com. You
>   can also contact GenWatt on the following numbers: Main:
>   810-543-1100Sales: 810-545-1222Customer Service & Support:
>   810-542-1233Fax: 810-545-1001I am confident GenWatt will serve you
>   well and hope to see our relationship=

Comment: findAll('p') returns a list with all '<p...>' in your HTML. You can get all 'p's content with  [p.getText() for p in parsedContent.findAll('p')] or all content this way: content = '\n'.join([p.getText() for p in parsedContent.findAll('p')])

Comment: for paragraph in parsedContent.findAll('p'):
        value = paragraph.text
        print value
like this right
I do not understand the content you mentioned

Comment: How to parse the &nsbp; or how to repalce the &nbsp; with <space>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's inspect the result of `soup.findAll('p')`

```
python -i test.py
----------
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bodytext = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth").text
parsedContent = BeautifulSoup(bodytext, 'html.parser')

paragraphs = soup.findAll('p')
----------

>> type(paragraphs)
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'> 
>> issubclass(type(paragraphs), list) 
True # It's a list
```

Can you see? It's a list of all paragraphs. If you want to access their content you will need iterate over the list or access an element by an index, like a normal list.

```
>> # You can print all content with a for-loop
>> for p in paragraphs:
>>     print p.getText()
Earth (otherwise known as the world (...)
According to radiometric dating and other sources of evidence (...)
...    

>> # Or you can join all content
>> content = []
>> for p in paragraphs:
>>     content.append(p.getText())
>> 
>> all_content = "\n".join(content)
>>
>> print(all_content)
Earth (otherwise known as the world (...) According to radiometric dating and other sources of evidence (...)
```

Using [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) your code will looks like:

```
parsedContent = BeautifulSoup(bodytext)
body = '\n'.join([p.getText() for p in parsedContent.findAll('p')]
```

> When I use
>
> ```
> body = parsedContent.find('p').getText()
> ```
>
> It fetches the first line of the content and it is not printing the
>   remaining lines.

Do `parsedContent.find('p')` is exactly [the same](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) that do `parsedContent.findAll('p')[0]`

```
>> parsedContent.findAll('p')[0].getText() == parsedContent.find('p').getText()
True
```

Comment: When extracting all the paragraphs, In-between the lines I get **&nbsp;** how to avoid this or how to replace with the <space>